# Specify area on a image

Tags: jquery, html

i try to do on a image specify one area where the user can click and go to other page. i try to use hotspotter editor and write the code below. but nothing happend, i dont understand what i do wrong.
if someone have an another solution for this it would be awesome.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-hotspotter-1.7.2.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-hotspotter-1.7.2.min.js"></script>



<div data-role="content" id="test">
            <div class="hs-area">
            <img src="imagens/HomeHorizontal.jpg"/>     
        <div class="hs-wrap"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.pt"><div data-activeon="click" data-dim="378,224,0" data-coord="646,0" class="shadow-spot"></div></a>
            <div
            class="tt-wrap">
                <div data-anim="goin" data-dir="top" class="tip-tooltip"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hs-wrap">
        <div data-activeon="click" data-dim="378,222,0" data-coord="646,223" class="shadow-spot"></div>
        <div class="tt-wrap">
            <div data-dir="top" data-anim="goin" class="tip-tooltip"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hs-wrap">
        <div data-activeon="click" data-dim="378,229,0" data-coord="646,445" class="shadow-spot"></div>
        <div class="tt-wrap">
            <div data-dir="top" data-anim="goin" class="tip-tooltip"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: How about just using a plain old image map ?

Comment: gotta love image maps!

Comment: doesnt need jquery library for that?

Comment: Image maps are plain HTML. Give it a Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about loading the image in background of a div with relative position and just add link elements as block with absolute positioning? shouldn't this work exactly for what you're doing?

**HTML**

```
<div id="example-image">
    <a href="#example-link" class="hotspot" style="top:40px;left:80px;width:50px;height:50px;">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="#example-link2" class="hotspot" style="bottom:80px;right:100px;width:20px;height:40px;">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#example-image { 
   position:relative;
   width: 500px;
   height: 200px;
   background:transparent url('example.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}

#example-image .hotspot {
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
}
```